# "This device isn't eligible for the requested build."

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer, xcode-organizer

I have an iPhone 3GS with 4.3 firmware. I downloaded a 3.1.3 firmware and was hoping to restore the iPhone using Organizer. But! I got the following error:

**"This device isn't eligible for the requested build."**

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no officially supported way to downgrade the firmware of an iPhone.

Apple only allows upgrading to a later version.

Comment: No Way! :O ... How am I suppose to test my app on earlier versions >.< (on an Actual Device .. Not Simulator)

Comment: Then you should have multiple devices with multiple firmware. Above answer is damn correct and you can not downgrade firmware at all.

Comment: eBay can be a useful source of older devices.

Answer (score 2):

Look up SHSH saving, with utilities such as TinyUmbrella. Its commonly used by jailbreakers to allow rollbacks. Ive been saving my SHSH since it was introduced around OS3.1.x, and it lets me go back to any iOS version from iOS5beta to iOS3.1.3 etc.

This is because apple need to confirm the software update with a SHSH key. TinyUmbrella will save them and spoof them if you want to downgrade later. Although it won't let you go back, you would start saving SHSH's for current iOS builds, allowing rollbacks in the future...

Comment: Unfortunately, am not jailbroken :)

Comment: you dont have to be. Simply use the program to save the SHSH's, and when you need them, use the utility to spoof apple verification and restore back to older OS's. By saving mine, I can restore back, no jailbreak anywhere!